# Can the Rata Sum city cube be seen from the world?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there a spot in the game where you can actually see the city cube on the horizon? Or get any external view of the city cube at all in the game?

By viewable in game I'm thinking more about the outside of the city cube being visible in the horizon or 'light box' of an adjoining zone such as Metrica Province.

Comment: I doubt it since guild wars works with 'instances' of pieces of the world. This means that every 'area' is loaded seperatly.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma: That doesn't mean they can't be geographically consistent. For instance, the very tall ship above the north entrance to Lion's Arch can be seen both from LA and from Gendarran Fields - in fact, you can use a glitch to position yourself atop the ship if you're patient and skilled. :-) Oh, and I think you meant "sepAratEly". Why do people have so much trouble with that word?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter what i meant was that Guild wars doesnt register the different areas ( you can only get from one area to the next via the designated routes in each area or via waypoints.) To elaborate on my point, if all the walls of Lions Arch became un-solid and you were able to walk straight through them you're still not loaded in that area since you didnt go through the required waypoint. The game still thinks you're in the instance you were in before. So even if you can get vision in the other instance its not actually live and its only what the game wants you to see.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma And that's exactly the point - developers will often add in versions of the terrain in other zones to preserve the sense of scale. These won't include any NPCs or any of the dynamic content you may see if you were actually in the associated zone, they're just there for immersion and the idea of a cohesive world. The question asks if such an 'immersion' piece exists for the city cube of Rata Sum.

Comment: @Psychemaster So now someone only has to answer 'yes' or 'no' and copy our comments to get the answer with the technical explanation ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This screen is the best I could do. It was taken from the eastern edge of the Snaff Memorial Lab, just outside the Rata Sum cube on the southwest side.

[image]